# Несложная функция по работе с числами

Tags: php, функции

Всем привет, извиняюсь за невнятный заголовок, суть в следующем:
нужна функция, которая возвращала бы в зависимости от числа соответствующий ему диапазон,
примерно так:

```
//число от 100 до 199 -> возвращаем 100
//число от 200 до 299 -> возвращаем 200
...
//конкретное число 18049 -> получаем 18000 (так как оно входит в первую сотню 18-й тысячи)
```

ну и так далее
Заранее благодарю за любые советы! Буду очень признателен за листинг кода, сам не осиливаю))

Comment: напиши сначала эту функцию на русском, а потом переводи на пхп. Тут всего пара строк кода

Comment: значит сложная...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function foo(int $n): int {
    return (int)($n / 100) * 100;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!